# TFS Delete duplicated users after domain change

Tags: tfs

We've just migrated our TFS 2013.3 server to a new domain.

It all appeared to go to plan - I migrated the server and then migrated the Identities successfully, but instead of *changing* user identities to their new domain accounts, it has just added new accounts so now everybody is in the system *twice*.

In general I've been able to mitigate the symptoms of this, but it has broken user capacities in Web Access - each user's name appears *twice*, and their capacity graph only shows correctly if both names have the same capacity value assigned to them. One user does not get a capacity graph at all even if we attempt this awful workaround.

I could easily delete the old users from [Tfs_Configuration.dbo.tbl_Identity] and/or [tbl_TeamConfigurationCapacity] but I have no idea if this would be a safe thing to do, or what references to these entries might exist elsewhere in the database. (There shouldn't be any information linked to these users any more, as they have all been migrated, but that won't help me if deleting these rows corrupts the database). I may just have to snapshot the VM and give it a try to see what happens, as this is a complete showstopper.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: With "migrated the Identities succesfully" did you did this with the TFS Config Identities command http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253054.aspx or did you add all the identities of the names manually or by script?

Comment: Tip for the future: normally when I do this kind of migrations I always restore a back-up to a new TFS instance and try to do the migration on that machine first... With this you verify if the migration will be performed as expected.

Comment: @mrtentje: I carefully followed the instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms404883.aspx (so yes, I did use TfsConfig Identities). Thanks for the advice - there are too many documented ways to migrate TFS instances, and usually most of them cause trouble. I've been using and migrating TFS since 2005 and it still impresses me how fragile it is - it's easy to break and impossible to fix once broken :-(

Comment: If you edit any of the TFS Databases yourself you invalidate your support from MSFT.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have got around the problem. In case it helps the next guy, ...

- The Identities table records all known users (on the old and new domain). This means people appear twice in places like "Assigned to" on work items (and if their display names are the same, it's hard to differentiate the old and new domain usernames). However, if you set up your TFS groups so that only your new domain users are in them, then you can edit the work item type Templates for your work items and set the Allowed Values rule on the Assigned-To field to only allow people in the groups (e.g. `[global]\Team Foundation Server Users`), then only the currently valid usernames appear in the Assigned-to drop-downs.
- The problem in the capacities page is because each iteration stores a list of the relevant users at the time it was created. So after a few iterations (when you reach the next one that has not yet been "used"), the old entries will disappear. In the intervening iterations you seem to have to enter the capacity value twice (on both instances of the user's name) but make sure that any holiday bookings are only assigned to one of the two instances, and then the capacity graphs seem to work ok.

So it looks like filtering out the unwanted users and then just waiting for a couple of iterations will be enough to clean away the problems. It'd still be nice to know if there is any way to ever clean up the database and flush out all the unwanted user references though.

Comment: They only way to solve this problem is not to have it in the first place. You need to remove all permission on the new domain to TGS prior to a migration so that you can convert the identities. If you follow the domain migration instructions then you do not get this issue.

Comment: TFS didn't exist on the domain, ergo it had no permissions?! I followed the instructions very carefully and it screwed my user accounts, screwed the groups and permissions, and broke the web access and reports so badly that the only way I could recover them was to migrate the whole lot to a brand new server and then spend 3 days rebuilding things. After 9 years managing TFS, I'm not a TFS noob, but it's fragile and the instructions are cryptic for anyone who didn't write TFS+SharePoint+SQL, and in any of these procedures there is *always* an "unexpected" blocking error, often unsolvable.

Comment: That's is not the way things usually happen. Usually with domain migrations your IT Team helpfully push all of the groups across, this gives users permission to the server in the new domain, it sync's accounts and boom you have an issue. I have never ended up with duplicate permissions and I have done a few upgrade too.

Answer (score 0):

The names are added twice probably because the old identity is (in)directly still a member of the contributor group. Removing the old identity from all the TFS groups in Web Access should solve the problem.

Comment: Ah, if only that were possible. There are groups and users from the old domain that the web-access admin pages won't let me remove. (In some cases the expected 'remove' option simply isn't there, and in the other cases clicking the remove option spits out an error telling me I have to go to a different page to remove them, but the page it instructs me to use is the one I'm already on. Sigh. Thanks for your suggestions though. This is why I'm fishing for lower-level suggestions of how to manually remove them.