# TFS Gated Checkin fails when checking in the changeset after a succesfull build

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, build-server, gated-checkin

I'm working with TFS version 2015 SP3 and I'm having problems with creating a working Gated Checkin Build definition.

The Build proces steps are empty to prevent a failing build.

When the Build succeeds de build server tries to check in de gated changes and fail. The error message is:

> The shelveset _Build_56625;Build\ead50f13-855a-45bd-9417-778e04e6fdfe
>   could not be found for check-in

From what I can gather it has to do with the fact the build server uses the GUID of the build-user instead of the username. (see image below).

[image: Error]
**Build log**

```
2016-09-27T14:22:59.3450903Z Checking if artifacts directory exists: C:\Agent_3\_work\1\a
2016-09-27T14:22:59.3450903Z Deleting artifacts directory.
2016-09-27T14:22:59.3607099Z Creating artifacts directory.
2016-09-27T14:22:59.3607099Z Checking if test results directory exists: C:\Agent_3\_work\1\TestResults
2016-09-27T14:22:59.3607099Z Deleting test results directory.
2016-09-27T14:22:59.3763337Z Creating test results directory.
2016-09-27T14:22:59.4232406Z Starting: Get sources
2016-09-27T14:22:59.4544938Z Entering TfvcSourceProvider.PrepareRepositoryAsync
2016-09-27T14:22:59.4544938Z localPath=C:\Agent_3\_work\1\s
2016-09-27T14:22:59.4544938Z clean=True
2016-09-27T14:22:59.4544938Z sourceVersion=68725
2016-09-27T14:22:59.4544938Z mappingJson={"mappings":[{"serverPath":"$/xxx","mappingType":"map","localPath":"\\"}]}
2016-09-27T14:22:59.4544938Z Syncing repository: xxx(TFVC)
2016-09-27T14:22:59.4544938Z workspaceName=ws_1_18
2016-09-27T14:23:00.3451244Z Undo any pending changes under workspace.
2016-09-27T14:23:01.2669675Z No inconsistencies were found to clean up.
2016-09-27T14:23:01.7044792Z Workspace Name: ws_1_18;Build\ead50f13-855a-45bd-9417-778e04e6fdfe
2016-09-27T14:23:01.7669760Z tf unshelve Gated_2016-09-27_04.22.53.2745;MyDomain\MyUser
2016-09-27T14:23:02.2413159Z edit: C:\Agent_3\_work\1\s\app\xxx\xxx.ts
2016-09-27T14:23:02.5225711Z Successfully unshelved Gated_2016-09-27_04.22.53.2745;MyDomain\MyUser into workspace ws_1_18;Build\ead50f13-855a-45bd-9417-778e04e6fdfe
2016-09-27T14:23:02.5225711Z tf get /version:68725
2016-09-27T14:23:03.0187586Z tf shelve _Build_56625 /replace
2016-09-27T14:23:03.1906333Z Successfully created new shelveset _Build_56625;Build\ead50f13-855a-45bd-9417-778e04e6fdfe
2016-09-27T14:23:03.2999952Z Done syncing repository xxx to version 68725 (workspace version C68725)
2016-09-27T14:23:03.2999952Z Leaving TfvcSourceProvider.PrepareRepositoryAsync
2016-09-27T14:23:03.4093700Z Running tasks
```

**Yes... I've read:**

[On Premise Gated Check-in Fails with "The shelveset ... could not be found for check-in"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364507/on-premise-gated-check-in-fails-with-the-shelveset-could-not-be-found-for-c)
- But I'm not willing to dump 5 years of history just to get this to work.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8016349e-88dd-4fe1-aa6b-13c8d897985f/tfs-2015-on-premise-gated-checkin-fails-with-the-shelveset-could-not-be-found-for-checkin?forum=tfsbuild 
- This question gives me some insight but no working solutions.

**We've tried**

- Creating a new agent
- Trowing away the local workspaces

Comment: Works well with my TFS15. It's hard to troubleshooting this issue since we don't have your environment. Even though you have mentioned create a new team project is not your solution. However, you still can create one for test to narrow down this issue and see if gated check- in build works on the new created one?

Comment: Have encountered an issue which only occurs on the project collection upgraded  from TFS2013 but works well with new created TFS 2015  project collection.

Comment: I have created a new project, created a new builddefinition, added gated checkin. Then checked in a new file. The build failed with a similar error:
[Error]The shelveset _Build_56722;Build\ead50f13-855a-45bd-9417-778e04e6fdfe could not be found for check-in

Comment: How about create a new team project collection and team Project ?  Which one are you running your build agent, Run as a service or Run interactively ?  Did you build service account  have enough permission to check-in the changeset?

Comment: Normal Gated Checkins using the 'old' xaml builddefinition still work.

Comment: Looks like  not related to your build service account. Then the most possibility is related to your team project collection or local workspace. Have a try with jessehouwing 's task "Update gated changes" to the build as the last step. It updates the shelveset and may possibly create it with the correct account for you to at least have the build succeed.  https://github.com/jessehouwing/vsts-tfvc-tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of our problems was a double Build Identity in the Tfs_Configuration database.

With the following query you can check double identities:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Identity WHERE PartitionId = 1 AND TypeId = 8
```

Comment: which field is the one that is doubled? (there are a few Identity/identifier fields)

Comment: Hi @StingyJack it has been a while. Are you having a similar problem?

Comment: Yep, but only things like Display Name are dupes in the table

Comment: The sysadmin who fixed this problem has left the company. I can't find what he did to fix the duplication. 
Maybe this SO question helps?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449926/tfs-delete-duplicated-users-after-domain-change